# Tweepy Twitter API command results

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I'm using tweepy to data mine stuff on twitter and while using the commands of the API the results look pretty weird. Should the results be like this when I use this code?

This is my code

```
import oauth, tweepy
import csv

list_user = []
list_user_follower = []
number = 0

with open('tweets.csv', 'rb') as user:
    reader = csv.reader(user, delimiter=",")
    for i in reader:
        list_user.insert(number, i[0])
        number += 1

def init():
    global api
    consumer_key = "...."
    consumer_secret = "...."
    access_key = "...."
    access_secret = "...."
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    print api.followers(list_users[0])

init()
```

This is the result. Take note that this isn't the full results since it was too long to put here.

```
[User(follow_request_sent=False, has_extended_profile=False, profile_use_background_image=True, profile_sidebar_fill_color=u'DDEEF6'
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that looks correct - your API request is returning the first entry in a list of users. The [Tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#user-methods) clearly states that the return value from this call is a list of User objects. You're printing that straight to the console. The values contained in a [User object](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users) are documented in Twitter's API documentation.